# What design options can I go for when fitting a lot of content in a poster?

Tags: posters, layout

My boss has been wanting me to design a promotional poster that can be used for both 18x24in poster and a letter sized one page stand.

I have been having trouble designing a layout that would work for both letter size and poster size. There is so much content that I need to fit into one sheet. If I design a poster and would want to shrink it down to a letter sized page, all the contents would be ineligible. I had previously designed a letter sized page that would be able to expand to poster size page, but my boss wanted more of a poster feel to it, meaning more illustrative or with pictures... Is there an industry measure to tell if too much content will not be ideal for allowing both poster and letter sized page visible? Any good suggestions on layouts or templates that would allow lots of contents to be visible regardless whether it's the 18x24in poster or the letter sized page?

There is a total of 1.5 pages of contents if font is 9 in word doc. The poster will be in both Chinese and English whether on individual page or on the same page.

*Previous posted images deleted.

Comment: Sounds as if you simply have too much content and an Editor would be helpful.

Comment: @Scott the content is already edited... sadly the boss wants to have every words presented.

Comment: "Editor" doesn't necessarily mean "correct typos" It often means remove content to better express the message. With a great deal of content you may be restricted to 2 columns of 7pt type.

Comment: Realize few, if any, here are going to copy the text and start laying out the project to provide you with design ideas. We can offer suggestions on what you've done. However, we're not here to design for you. And to me, 50% of that copy could be cut and the message made more clear. Every possible detail of every discount doesn't need to be detailed on the promotion. But, I'm not the boss.

Comment: @Scott yeah...unfortunately you are not the boss :( I really do want to cut 50% of the texts as well. Too bad there isn't an ideal layout that everyone knows about to fit that much contents in while capable of drastic resizing. Would you have any pointers though without having to cut the texts at all? I do no need a design presented. Simply pointers in plains words. Thank you!

Comment: In all honesty, with the content I saw.. it's not a promotional offer. It *may* be a brochure. However, there's simply too much copy to effectively design a poster or a single-sided letter-sized sheet. If your boss is **adamant** about including it all... set it on 6pt type and let him complain. He may not take your word that there's too much until he sees it.

Comment: @Scott I surely plan on doing so. sigh...bosses...

Answer (score 2):

> There is so much content that I need to fit into one sheet

Then that's probably not a poster. A poster typically has one item of information. With perhaps a few ancillary secondary bits that support the primary focus.

So, bottom line, your boss is asking you to make a poster--but not a poster. In  other words, there's a huge contradiction in your marching orders.

You need to explain to your boss that you can either make a poster, or you can make a detailed brochure. But they can't be one and the same. Perhaps it would be more beneficial if you were given the chance to design a poster *and* a brochure that worked together.

If there's just no getting around this contradictory demand, one suggestion would be to devote a large part of the real estate to 'the poster' and then a smaller part to the 'fine print content that they insist having on there'. So maybe something like this:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------
|    ______ _        ______         _                          |
|    | ___ (_)       | ___ \       | |                         |
|    | |_/ /_  __ _  | |_/ /__  ___| |_ ___ _ __               |
|    | ___ \ |/ _` | |  __/ _ \/ __| __/ _ \ '__|              |
|    | |_/ / | (_| | | | | (_) \__ \ ||  __/ |                 |
|    \____/|_|\__, | \_|  \___/|___/\__\___|_|                 |
|              __/ |  ___  ___                                 |
|             |___/   |  \/  |                                 |        
|                     | .  . | ___  ___ ___  __ _  __ _  ___   |
|                     | |\/| |/ _ \/ __/ __|/ _` |/ _` |/ _ \  |
|                     | |  | |  __/\__ \__ \ (_| | (_| |  __/  |
|                     \_|  |_/\___||___/___/\__,_|\__, |\___|  |
|                                                  __/ |       |
|                                                 |___/        |
|          _   _                                        _      |
|         ( ) ( )                                      ( )     |
|         | |_| |   __   _   _     _   _    _    _   _ | |     |
|         |  _  | /'__`\( ) ( )   ( ) ( ) /'_`\ ( ) ( )| |     |
|         | | | |(  ___/| (_) |   | (_) |( (_) )| (_) || |     |
|         (_) (_)`\____)`\__, |   `\__, |`\___/'`\___/'(_)     |
|                       ( )_| |   ( )_| |              (_)     |
|                       `\___/'   `\___/'                      |
|                                                              |
|--------------------------------------------------------------|   
| All the rest of the huge amount of content can go here in    |
| tiny type. The idea is that the top part is the 'poster' that|
| draws attention and then the person can move in to read the  |
| 'find print' without it detracting too much from the overall |
| 'poster feel'.                                               |
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

If you just can't get through to your boss regarding that issue, try a different tactic. Ask them to find some posters they really like to help you get an idea of the overall direction they have in their head. Odds are they'll find some posters that truly are posters...in that they will have maybe 3 lines of text rather than 2 pages worth of text. At that point you now have a visual that hopefully will get the point across.

Comment: Yeah, I ended up talked him into the possibility of having me design a brochure/poster pair. He kept giving suggestions and demands and at the same time telling me, "...but i didn't study graphic design. so you might know better." lol